# Why magento used deprecatedNode tag in model resource declaration in wishlist

Tags: magento, collections, model, magento-1.7

I have  seen  an  interesting thing in model configuration in config.xml. I am unknown  tags

```
<deprecatedNode>
```

in model class declaration.In a custom extension we just need  this type of model class declarion...

```
 <models>
            <[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>[module]_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </[module]>
            <[module]_mysql4>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <[module]>
                        <table>[module]</table>
                    </[module]>
                </entities>
            </[module]_mysql4>
        </models>
```

reference -http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

`But in magento existing modules like Wishlist` 's config.xml define model with **deprecatedNode** and   resourceModel declare with this pattern ...

```
<wishlist>
                <class>Mage_Wishlist_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>wishlist_resource</resourceModel>
            </wishlist>

            <wishlist_resource>

                <class>Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource</class>
                <deprecatedNode>wishlist_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
                <entities>
                    <wishlist>
                        <table>wishlist</table>
                    </wishlist>
                    <item>
                        <table>wishlist_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <table>wishlist_item</table>
                    </item>
                    <item_option><table>wishlist_item_option</table></item_option>
                </entities>
            </wishlist_resource>
```

WHY THIS TYPE OF  CODE USED IN MAGENTO

```
<resourceModel>wishlist_resource</resourceModel>
      <wishlist_resource>
```

**Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource**
                    **wishlist_mysql4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento versions after 1.6 the resource model is taken from the node `<..._resource>`.
The `<deprecatedNode>` is kept for backward compatibilty with old extensions which still use the `<..._mysql4>` node as resource model.

As you can see from the file: `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php` line 1230 (for Magento version 1.7.0):

```
// First - check maybe the entity class was rewritten
    $className = null;
    if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
        $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
    } else {
        /**
         * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
         * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
         * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
         */
        if ($config->deprecatedNode) {
            $deprecatedNode = $config->deprecatedNode;
            $configOld = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->$deprecatedNode;
            if (isset($configOld->rewrite->$class)) {
                $className = (string) $configOld->rewrite->$class;
            }
        }
    }
```